# Using bash (bash awk, sed) read a file and extract word matching prefix between quotes

Tags: bash, scripting, sed, awk, grep

I have a file containing (one per line). I would like to extract word between quotes starting with the some pattern. (in my case it is C_)

```
"PATTERNabcde"  sdfds  sdfds
"sdfsdfsdf"   sdfdsf sdfdsf
" PATTERNabc"          dfdsdfd
```

and I want to extract: `PATTERNabcde` `PATTERNabc`

**EDIT:**
I would like to ALSO extract word between quotes that don't start with the `$PATTERN`.

Comment: What parenthesis? Do you mean quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F\" '$2~/^[[:space:]]*PATTERN/{print $2}' file
```

This works if there is only one word enclosed in quotation marks or if the one that may start with pattern is always the first one; otherwise, you'd have to use a for cycle:

```
awk -F\" '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) if ($i ~/^[[:space:]]*PATTERN/ ) {print $i;next}}'
```

Comment: -F\" forces awk to use " as the field separator; then for every line, if the second field (the word enclosed in quotations marks) starts with zero or more spaces followed by PATTERN, it simply prints it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -rn 's/.*?".*?(PATTERN[^"]*)".*/\1/p'
```

- `-r` - extended regex
- `-n` - disabled auto-print
- `.*?` - zero or more characters, non-greedy
- `(` - open capturing group
- `[^"]` - any character but `"`
- `)` - close capturing group
- `\1` - first matching group
- `p` - print

We just replace every line with the first group.  If there is a replacement, we print.

Comment: that's great although it fails on "${PATTERN}abc${PATTERN}ghi"  it returns $PATTERNghi

Comment: @vehom, you didn't say there could be more than one per line.

Comment: sorry,  I said that it begins with $PATTERN between parentheses, which implied that anything can follow $PATTERN including $PATTERN, as long as the word ends before the closing parenthesis. And match only one word per line.  I still upvoted your answer =)

Comment: @vehom, there's no parenthesis in your question.

Comment: also please explain some parts of your sed, such as *?".*? and  )".*/\1.. thanks

Comment: `sed` is always greedy - in other words, it sees `.*?` as "zero or more characters followed by a question mark". On the other hand `.*\?` is "zero or more characters (optionally)" which is the same as `.*`.

Comment: `str="/* replace me */  not me  /* or me */"; regex='s|/\*.*?\*/|X|'; echo "$str" | sed -r "$regex"; echo "$str" | perl -pe "$regex"` gives "X" for the `sed -r` (greedy) and "X  not me  /* or me */" for the `perl -pe` (non-greedy). This is using GNU `sed` 4.2.1 and Perl 5.10.0. You are right about the `-r` in one sense, though. It inverts the meaning that I showed in my comment. With the `-r`, `.*?` means "zero or more characters (optionally)" which, as I said, is the same as `.*`. If you leave question marks out of your regex, it still works with the OP's example data.

Comment: @Dennis, I see what you're saying now; lazy is not an option even with `-r`.  That explains why it returns only the second pattern, rather than only the first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` as:

```
grep -Po '(?<=")\s*PATTERN[^"]*(?=")' file
```

[See it](http://www.ideone.com/yFMzB)